# Enforcing local invariance in a covariance (kernel) function

Tags: statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian, covariance, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am doing some Bayesian inference over a particular domain and the functions to be inferred are known to posses certain invariances (symmetries). In particular there are 2 types of invariance that I need to enforce: (1) a 2-fold rotational symmetry about a point (a,b), and (2) a line along which all function values should be identical.

### 2-fold rotational symmetry

The symmetry relation I need to enforce here is

$f(x,y) = f(2a-x,2b-y)$

which corresponds to a 2-fold rotation about the point (a,b). To force samples of the posterior distribution to respect this symmetry the covariance (kernel) function must respect this symmetry. I can enforce this in a straightforward way via the "sum over group orbits" method with

$k_{symm}(x,y,x',y') = k(x,y,x',y')+k(x,y,2a-x',2b-y')+k(2a-x,2b-y,x',y')+k(2a-x,2b-y,2a-x',2b-y')$

### Identifying points

For the second type of invariance I am stuck. The symmetry that I'm trying to enforce is

$f(0,y) = f(0,0)$

in other words all points along the line $x = 0$ should have the same function value. I have tried some kludgy computational hacks (e.g. extracting the correlation matrix from the covariance matrix, and setting the pair-wise correlation to 1 for all points where x = 0 and then reforming the covariance matrix), but they all result in a covariance (kernel) that is not positive definite (not even positive semi-definite). I have also tried finding the nearest symmetric positive definite matrix to my kludge-built one, but when I do the result is a valid positive definite kernel matrix that no longer enforces (even approximately) the $f(0,y) = f(0,0)$ constraint (i.e. it undoes my constraint).

**Any ideas how I can enforce the $f(0,y) = f(0,0)$ invariance in the covariance function?**

Comment: I do not understand what you are looking for exactly. Do you start with a RKHS and seek an expression for the kernel of the subspace of functions with those two properties or are you looking for any RKHS of functions having these properties? In the latter case, what else do you require in addition to the two properties?

Comment: I forgot: In the first case you should tell us the kernel you would like to modify.